# Pattern matching on user input Rust

Tags: rust, comparison, user-input

I just started learning Rust, and I'm currently trying to create a simple rock paper scissors game. I decided to create a main menu to choose between singleplayer and multiplayer as this

```rust
io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut choix)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
    choix = str::to_lowercase(&choix);
    match choix.as_str() {
        "singleplayer" => singleplayer(),
        "multiplayer" => multiplayer(),
        _ => println!("Unknown choice, please choose 'singleplayer' or 'multiplayer'"),
    }
    println!("End of game");
```

but the pattern matching does not seem to work properly, as shown by this execution:
[singleplayer execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgHbn.png)
what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `choix = choix.trim().to_lowercase();`

Comment: So this is the correct answer because the line break was also added to choix?

Comment: Yes. Entering "singleplayer" into the terminal would yield `"singleplayer\n"` in `choix`. Using `.trim()` will remove any beginning or trailing whitespace, which will make your `match` behave as you expect.